# RestTemplate with custom ConnectionPool?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-web

I'm using the following config to create a `RestTemplate` bean.

```
@Bean
@Primary
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

    return builder.requestFactory(() -> new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(factory))
            .build();
}
```

Problem: by default `HttpClient` is instantiated as follows:

```
org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder:

    String s = System.getProperty("http.keepAlive", "true");
    if ("true".equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
        s = System.getProperty("http.maxConnections", "5");
        int max = Integer.parseInt(s);
        poolingmgr.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(max);
        poolingmgr.setMaxTotal(2 * max);
    }
```

Thus by default having a maximum of 10 concurrent url connections on that rest template.

Question: how could I best configure the max total when using `spring-boot`? I did not find any `application.properties` entry to set it to a custom value.

Sidequestion: what does the property **per route** mean? Is a route `localhost:8080/myfirst`, and another route is `localhost:8080/mysnd`? Or are both the same route `localhost:8080`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm missunderstood your question.

It's simply: in `application.properties` you can create you own configuration. 
For example:

```
## Connection pool max size to appache http client
myProjectId.http.maxConnections=100
```

And then in you Bean/Service/Something else you can inject it by simple action

```
@Bean
public class HttpClient  {

    @Value( "${myProjectId.http.maxConnections}" )
    private int maxConnections;

    // some code below

}
```

Comment: Ok I thought I could maybe override the system property `http.maxConnections` with `application.properties` somehow...